# Increasing the time out time with OkHTTP

Tags: android, okhttp

So I am using a request builder to connect to my API so I can receive some data for my users to login. Sometimes because my API goes to sleep it will take more than the default 10 seconds to request, which makes my app report a socket timeout error.

I have looked at multiple examples but the answers seem to be deprecated or, I cant seem to make work.

```
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, requestBody);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(DataService.authUrl+DataService.policyName)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .addHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", DataService.authSubscriptionKey)
            .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("appId", "CB563848-4B41-4D30-9ABE-9DF30508EABB")
            .addHeader("hardwareId", Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID))
            .addHeader("versionNumber", Globals.versionName)
            .build();


    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() { blah blah blah
```

I have tried to add the `.setConnectTimeout` to my builder but that doesn't work.

I have tried to create an entirely new `OkHttpClient.Builder` but then that means I can't use my concurrent request.

and if I try to edit my client with 
`okHttpClient.connectTimeOut(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, it doesn't work.

I've googled many things but can't get this to work. Any suggestions are appreciated to increase my timeout time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public static WebService INSTANCE;
APIService mApiService;

public WebService() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES).readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    httpClient.interceptors().add(logging);
    httpClient.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
                                      @Override
                                      public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                          Request original = chain.request();

                                          // Customize the request
                                          Request request = original.newBuilder()
                                                  .header("Accept", "application/json")
                                                  .method(original.method(), original.body())
                                                  .build();

                                          Response response = chain.proceed(request);

                                          // Customize or return the response
                                          return response;
                                      }
                                  }
    );

    OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()

            .baseUrl(Constants.getInstance().URLLOCAL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    mApiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit excessive just to increase the timeout variable? Ive seen a few other examples user Retrofit, I can try them?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```